# Do limits of (continuous) functions have a meaning in the distribution sense?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, distribution-theory

This question came to my mind when working with distributions. We know that locally integrable functions can be realized as distributions. Particularly, if $f$ is locally integrable on $\Omega$, then for any $\phi \in C^{\infty}_c ( \Omega )$, we have the action of $f$ on $\phi$ given by

$$f ( \phi ) = \int\limits_{\Omega} f ( x ) \phi ( x )\, \mathrm{d}x.$$

Now, we also know that continuous functions are locally integrable, and hence can be realized as distributions. My question is whether we can make sense of the point values $f ( x )$ as distributions? Further, can we make sense of "$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow x_0} f ( x ) = f ( x_0 )$" in the sense of distributions? Any insights into this are appreciable!

Answer (score 3):

For a distribution $f$, it doesn't make much sense to talk about its value at a given point $x$. [The behavior of $f$ can be certainly localized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Localization_of_distributions), but still you need "infinitesimally small neighborhood of $x$" in order to properly describe the behavior of $f$ about $x$. In fact, you can even glimpse this issue when $f$ is a locally integrable function. An element of $L_{\text{loc}}^1(\Omega)$ is an equivalence class of functions that is insensitive of modification of function values on null sets. This renders the idea of "the value of $f(x)$" for locally integrable $f$ essentially meaningless.

If the point evaluation of a distribution is not the right choice, what will be the right type of data for encoding local information of a distribution? Also, once this issue has been addressed successfully, how do we define the limit of such data? One may imagine that the notion of germ might help. Unfortunately, however, germ is too restrictive for defining any useful topology on it. This means that we somehow need less sensitive way of localizing distributions. To this direction, googling seems to suggest that the following definition is a useful choice:

> **Definition.** Let $f$ and $g$ be distributions on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Then we say that $f \sim_x g$ if
>
> $$ \lim_{\lambda \to 0^+} |f(\varphi_x^{\lambda}) - g(\varphi_x^{\lambda})| = 0 $$
>
> for any $\varphi \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^d)$, where $\varphi_x^{\lambda}(z) = \lambda^{-d}\varphi(\lambda^{-1}(z - x))$.

(*Remark.* A uniform version of this definition has been used to formulate and prove [Hairer's reconstruction theorem for distributions](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.09287.pdf).)

Let us make several observations:

1. Clearly $\sim_x$ is an equivalence relation, which depends only on the restriction of $f$ and $g$ on arbitrary neighborhood of $x$. In other words, equivalence classes of $\sim_x$ is determined solely on the [germs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germ_(mathematics)) of distributions at $x$. We will denote the equivalence class of $f$ for $\sim_x$ by $[f]_x$.
2. If $f$ is a locally integrable function such that $\lim_{y \to x} f(y) = \ell$, then $[f]_x = [\ell]_x$ (where $\ell$ in RHS now represents the constant function with value $\ell$ everywhere). So, the relation $\sim_x$ captures the notion of pointwise value of continuous function.
3. Let $\mathcal{D}'_x$ denote the collection of all equivalence classes for $\sim_x$. Then we equip $\mathcal{D}'_x$ with the topology generated by the pseudometrics of the form
   $$ d_{\varphi}([f]_x, [g]_x) := \min\Bigl\{ 1, \, \limsup_{\lambda \to 0^+} |f(\varphi_x^{\lambda}) - g(\varphi_x^{\lambda})| \Bigr\} $$
   for $\varphi \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^d)$. It is routine to prove that $d_{\varphi}$ is indeed a well-defined pseudometric on $\mathcal{D}'_x$. Moreover, the resulting topology on $\mathcal{D}'_x$ is Hausdorff.
4. For each $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$, we introduce the translation operator $T_x$ on distributions defined by
   $$T_x f(\varphi(\cdot)) = f(\varphi(\cdot + x))$$
   and then identify $[f]_x$ with $[T_{-x}f]_0$. This makes sense, because if $f$ is a locally integrable function such that $\lim_{y \to x} f(y) = \ell$, then $[T_{-x}f]_0 = [\ell]_0$.

Using this formulation, we can prove:

> **Theorem.** Let $f \in C(\mathbb{R}^d)$. Then
> $$ \lim_{y \to x} \, [f]_y = [f]_x. $$

*Proof.* For any $\varphi \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^d)$, it follows that

$$ d_{\varphi}([f]_y, [f]_x)
= d_{\varphi}([T_{-y}f]_0, [T_{-x}f]_0)
= \min\left\{ 1, \, |f(y) - f(x)| \left| \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \varphi(z) \, \mathrm{d}z \right| \right\}
\to 0 $$

as $y \to x$. Therefore the desired claim follows. $\square$

Comment: Very interesting answer! Thank you!

Comment: The idea is quite interesting, and something that I now feel I could never have come up with on my own. I am not sure I understand it completely. Nevertheless, let me try for some time to go through it and digest and assimilate it.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh, The definition of $\sim_x$ requires that $$\lim_{\lambda \rightarrow 0^+} | f(\varphi_x^{\lambda}) - g(\varphi_x^{\lambda}) | = 0$$ holds for **all** $\varphi\in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d)$. An extreme case would be $\varphi\equiv0$ so that $d_{\varphi}([f]_x, [g]_x) = 0$ for any $[f]_x$ and $[g]_x$, and I believe that there is a non-trivial example of $\varphi$ that renders $d_{\varphi}$ only a pseudometric. Then for your second question, yes. The topology is generated by the sets of the form $\{[g]_x: d_{\varphi}([f]_x,[g]_x)<r\}$ for any $r>0$ and $\varphi$.

Comment: @SangchulLee: I understood it sometime later, which is why I deleted the comment. Thank you, anyway for the clarification!

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh, No problem :) Also, let me clarify that this definition is not something you will encounter in any textbook. My purpose was to give a reasonable definition of "localized distribution" without losing too much information, and for this goal, I tweaked some definition that has been appearing some recent papers. This does not necessarily mean that this definition has some research value, though. So, you may consider it as a purely recreational brain teaser.

Comment: @SangchulLee: In my belief, this "tweaked" definition might have some value after all. If we are able to give these type of limits, even in the sense of our equivalence classes, I believe it might be helpful in some reconstruction (inversion) problems, where we may not be able to reconstruct the function in the classical sense, but at least in this equivalence class of distribution sense..

Comment: @SangchulLee: Could you mention where you have seen these type of definitions recently in research articles? I would like to explore them as well.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh, For example, check [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.09287.pdf) (that is also linked in my answer).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142083/discussion-between-aniruddha-deshmukh-and-sangchul-lee).